# Initial setup of RPi 4model b headless

Tags: ssh, headless

I bought a new Raspberrypi 4 model b, but I didn't have a monitor or keyboard so I decided to set it up headlessly. I installed raspbain buster(not lite) on a 32GB sd card and created a wpa_supplicant.conf file containing ssid and password of the network I wanted it to connect to and I created an extension less file named SSH in the boot partition. Upon, inserting and booting up, the RPi connected to the network in the wpa_supplicant.conf file, my laptop was also connected to the same network, but upon ruuning an Advanced IP scan, the RPi didn't show up nor did its IP address. I gave the ping raspberypi command in command prompt and this is what it gave:
C:\Users\yasha>ping raspberrypi

```
Pinging raspberrypi.local [**2401:4900:3364:cde1:8b3d:32b2:13be:b1ab**] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from **2401:4900:3364:cde1:8b3d:32b2:13be:b1ab:** time=6ms
Reply from **2401:4900:3364:cde1:8b3d:32b2:13be:b1ab:** time=3ms
Reply from **2401:4900:3364:cde1:8b3d:32b2:13be:b1ab:** time=4ms
Reply from **2401:4900:3364:cde1:8b3d:32b2:13be:b1ab:** time=4ms

Ping statistics for 2401:4900:3364:cde1:8b3d:32b2:13be:b1ab:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 3ms, Maximum = 6ms, Average = 4ms
```

How do I get the RPi's IP address to SSH into it?

Comment: 2401:4900:3364:cde1:8b3d:32b2:13be:b1ab **IS** the ip6 address

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6  That one looks a public address (not an `fd` prefixed private network ala IPv4 `192.168` ), which is odd.

Comment: Could you show us the contents of the `wpa_supplicant.conf` file that you set at the beginning on the micro SD card?